# Is it possible to filter based on a custom column in a Calendar View?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, calendar

So I have a simple SharePoint List with some custom columns of type "Single line of text", such as "Client Name". When I am in the Calendar View, I only have very limited filtering options, mainly Title, Employee, Begin and End dates. Is there a way to add a filter for "Client Name", where I could select in this same view? I do see an option to filter based on client name from "All Items" view but not from calendar.

There are some filter settings in the List Setting view but those are hardcoded so to say. I need to be able to quickly switch back and forth.

Comment: Where do you see the filter options for Title, Employee, Begin and End dates in modern calendar view, in filters pane? Can you add screenshot of it to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to add single line of text column in filters pane in [SharePoint online modern experience calendar view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/):

1. Go to your calendar view
2. Click on "Switch view options" drop down and select **Add or remove fields**:

   [image]
3. Select your single line of text column and click Apply:

   [image]
4. You can also add/show columns in calendar view using classic experience view settings page: [Conditional Formatting in Calendar View is not showing a Column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306473/conditional-formatting-in-calendar-view-is-not-showing-a-column/306476#306476)
5. Now, open the filters pane from calendar view and you will see the single line of text column:

   [image]

**Note**: column in filter pane will be shown only when you have calendar events/items with some data in that text column in currently opened month (like January 2021 in above image). Here is the list data for reference:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

To add more columns in the filter pane, you can try pin/unpin the required columns in the filer pane from here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So interestingly, this works if I disable all columns from "Add or remove fields" and only leave "Client Name". But now another filter which was before - column with type "Person or Group" is gone. Is that because Sharepoint only allows 4 filters at any given time? If I enable both of them, only one is showing.

Comment: Yes, SharePoint by default shows only 4 columns in the filter pane. You can try pinning the columns in filter pane then add more columns in the view by following the steps in answer - again pin the required columns (check updated answer).

Comment: You're right! I spend a whole day try to get this to work, and now it finally works! Thank you so much! It's quite unintuitive I would say.