# Changing color in calendar view to show different locations

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calendar, json-formatting

I would like to visually show when the locations are different.

So I have 2 rooms that we use Room 1 and Room 2 (location is a free text value but we would use the same text).

I would like these in a calendar view to have different colors, to distinguish between the different session.

Is this possible? or is JSON only for list view?

Comment: Are you talking about the [Modern SharePoint list calendar view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)? or classic calendar view or SharePoint default "Events" web part?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [SharePoint Online Modern list calendar view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/), you can use SharePoint JSON conditional formatting rules to color code the events based on columns (like Location) in the list.

**Example**:

List Data:

[image]

Conditional formatting rules & calendar color coding:

[image]

---

Steps to apply conditional formatting:

1. Go to your SharePoint modern calendar view
2. Click on Switch view options drop down and select **Format current view**:

   [image]
3. Select "Month" in drop down and click **Manage rules**:

   [image]
4. Add rules as per your requirements and save the changes:

   [image]

---

**Note**: After creating a calendar view and before applying conditional formatting, you may need to show/include location column in your calendar view settings.

Refer this threads for more information and steps for same: [Conditional Formatting in Calendar View is not showing a Column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306473/conditional-formatting-in-calendar-view-is-not-showing-a-column/306476#306476)